# How did the info in the drop-down box come from when to open `127.0.0.1/login.php` in my chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, php

A simple php file named as `login.php`.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="get">
            user:
            <input type="text" name="userName" size="12">
            pass:
            <input type="text" name="pass" size="12">
            <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

How  did the info in the drop-down box (x1,x2,x3,x4),come from when to open `127.0.0.1/login.php` in my chrome?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a dropdown, but a text box. The x1 x2 x3 you are seeing is text that was inserted in another text box, most likely on another website. Clear your browser data for history and fill-in data.. Ctrl shift del for chrome. Then you'll see it has nothing to do with the php file.